# Access Token - Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, mobile, facebook-access-token

I would like to develop a mobile application that uses the Facebook Graph API.

For testing, I used an "access token" that I found on the Internet and it works ok for me. In the future, I would like to create my own access token and release this app. Is there any problem if the same "access token" is used for 1000, 10000 or more at the same time?

Comment: If you want to use access tokens on the client side, then you should use a user access token. You get one by having the user login.